# How to fetch array from mysqli_fetch_assoc?

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

My method returns an array of answers by mysqli_fetch_assoc. I try to extract the answer according to the index. The result does not match expectations. I would get the same answers(should be three answers).

method:

```
function getAnswers($id_question)
{
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM answers WHERE question_id = '. $id_question;

    $this->db->query($sql);
    while ($answers = $this->db->fetchAssoc())
    {
        return $answers;
    }
}
```

use:

```
$answers = getAnswers(1);
foreach($answers as $a)
{
    echo $a['answer'];
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($answers);
echo '</pre>';
```

out:

```
11a1
Array
(
    [id_answer] => 1
    [question_id] => 1
    [answer] => answer 1
    [truth] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning only the first set. You will have to pack the data into an array and then return the array:

```
function getAnswers($id_question)
{
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM answers WHERE question_id = '. $id_question;

    $this->db->query($sql);
    $data = array();
    while ($answers = $this->db->fetchAssoc())
    {
        $data[] = $answers;
    }

    return $data;
}
```